# Fast compression in C++ and decompression in C#

Tags: c#, c++, compression

#### Overview

I am working on a client-server application. The client is written in C++ (working on Windows, planning to support Linux) and the server is a .NET RESTful service. I need to HTTP POST some data to the server. The data is a unicode `string` that I need to compress using any fast compression algorithm (needs to be light on CPU). On the server I need to decompress raw bytes and get a string.

#### Problem

I cannot decompress raw bytes and I end up with decompressor's output buffers stay intact.

#### I tried

I have tried using [Google Snappy](http://code.google.com/p/snappy/), there is only a C/C++ version and any .NET ports don't appear to be finished. I also checked [LZ4](http://code.google.com/p/lz4/), where compression/decompression works in a *single* language, but when I try to use *both* - I cannot decompress data correctly (the decompressed bytes are set to 0s).

#### Question

Has anyone tried using a fast C/C++ compression and C# decompression? Any recommendations?

<sub>Client application shall not use more than 5% of CPU - that's a vague requirement I have. I plan to try gzip and maybe deflate, but I am not sure if I can configure compression levels there or whether it will work in both C/C++ and C#. Client collects some near real time data into a small buffer, when that buffer gets full it shall be compressed and POSTed. The whole OS process shall take less than 5% of the machine's CPU. A buffer is roughly posted 2 times a second which creates a traffic of about 2Kb/sec.</sub>

Comment: For what value of "light on CPU"? Would plain zlib/gzip be okay?

Comment: @oleksii That requirement doesn't make much sense to me. Are you saying it's okay if the compression takes an hour, but during that hour uses only 5% CPU? Why exactly do you have such a requirement?

Comment: Gzip is probably what you are after. However, the problems you mentioned are not problems of the compression algorithms but you implementation. You should ask about that specifically on stackoverflow.

Comment: @svick a client collects some *near* real time data into a small buffer, when that buffer gets full it shall be compressed and POSTed. The whole OS process shall take less than 5% of the machine's CPU. A buffer is roughly posted 2 times a second which creates a traffic of about 2Kb/sec.

Comment: I really doubt you will have any CPU load issues using gzip if your data is in the order of 2Kb/sec.

Comment: Do you mean that binary produced by LZ4 C# version are not compatible with the LZ4 decoder C/C++ version ?

Comment: Your LZ4 issue sounds like maybe an endianess problem or a 64/32-bit mismatch.

Comment: If you have problems to tranfer binary data over the network, you should work on that, this has nothing to do with compression. If you can't find a better solution, try Convert.ToBase64 / Convert.FromBase64 (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library)/system.convert.tobase64string%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: @ATTracker exactly, but the other way around. LZ4 C++ encoder produces binary that cannot be decoded in C#, at least on my machine.

Comment: @DocBrown I do not have problems transferring data over the network. I have problems with compressing in C++ and decompressing in C#. My test application compresses a file locally in C++ and locally I run a decompressor in C#, that fail to decompress a local file.

Comment: @oleksii: if that is the case, I guess you can use almost any native C++ compression lib by writing a adding a C++/CLI wrapper to make it C# compatible (or if the interface is simple enough, you just use P/Invoke). That way, you can use the exactly same lib for both programs.

Comment: @DocBrown I considered that option... But that route comes with [lots of troubles](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3662911/706456). A server is hosted on IIS so there are some security and performance  issues. An ideal solution will produce binaries in the same environment-independent format.

Answer (score 9):

If anybody interested I ended up using gzip from [zlib](http://www.zlib.net/). Never figured out why LZ4 doesn't work, as suggested in the comments this could be an endianess problem or a 64/32-bit mismatch. However, I tested this on a single machine compressing and decompressing a local file. The same compilation settings worked for gzip.

C/C++ sample compressor code

```
int compress_one_file(char *infilename, char *outfilename)
 {
    FILE *infile = fopen(infilename, "rb");
    gzFile outfile = gzopen(outfilename, "wb");
    if (!infile || !outfile) return -1;

    char inbuffer[128];
    int num_read = 0;
    unsigned long total_read = 0, total_wrote = 0;
    while ((num_read = fread(inbuffer, 1, sizeof(inbuffer), infile)) > 0) {
       total_read += num_read;
       gzwrite(outfile, inbuffer, num_read);
    }
    fclose(infile);
    gzclose(outfile);
 }
```

C# sample decompressor code

```
public static void Decompress(FileInfo fileToDecompress)
{
    using (FileStream originalFileStream = fileToDecompress.OpenRead())
    {
        string currentFileName = fileToDecompress.FullName;
        string newFileName = currentFileName + ".decompressed";

        using (FileStream decompressedFileStream = File.Create(newFileName))
        {
            using (GZipStream decompressionStream = 
                new GZipStream(originalFileStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            {
                decompressionStream.CopyTo(decompressedFileStream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, I will have this in mind when I get a similar task to solve ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Both LZ4 and Snappy has been ported to .NET recently.

You can find LZ4 .NET port here at http://lz4net.codeplex.com.
You can find Snappy .NET port (actually P/Invoke wrapper) here at http://snappy4net.codeplex.com.

You can also check [performance comparison (of .NET ports) here](http://lz4net.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Comparison%20to%20other%20algorithms).

To answer your question I did use both to test C++ compression and C# decompression and it works fine.

**Disclaimer**: yes, both LZ4 and Snappy has been ported/wrapped by me.

Comment: Since you only mention P/Invoke on Snappy, does that mean that the LZ4 port is a real re-implementation?

Comment: It's MixedMode, C++/CLI, Unsafe C# or Safe C#. You can choose which one you want or even let it choose the best one automatically.

Comment: Thank you for your work! I've only had a quick look yet but it also seems like a very good analysis. Could you add a "whole picture" diagram, containing all options (save/unsafe/native), too?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at 7-zip's LZMA format. [here](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html)

I have only used their compression utilities (but not their SDK) but they are excellent. The compression format is portable across language and platform and they claim support for both C# and C++

Comment: "zlma"? The compression algorithm is called "LZMA" (and so is one of the file formats).

Comment: @jan -- the fumbling fingers strike again -- will fix.

Answer (score -2):

You must develop a program that will run in the console. Your program will be called "TP2.exe" and
has three parameters:

1. the name of an input file,
2. a boolean (true or false) indicating whether you want to compress
   the input file or unpack.
3. the name of the output file (the result will be written to this
   file.)

For example, if you run the program with the following command in the console:
TP2.exe test.txt true test2.txt
Your program will read the file test.txt as input and writes the compressed file test2.txt output.
Another example: if you run the program with the following command in the console:

```
TP2.exe test2.txt false test.txt
```

Your program will read the file and write test2.txt the decompressed file test.txt output. Your program should use the method of compression / decompression simply discussed in the course is based on the use of a self-organized list.

An example file uncompressed and compressed file example is provided as an example of CLIC. For the work is simple to make, you can assume that the sentences are already cut into words and that there is a single word
per line.

Finally, at the implementation level, it is recommended to use a linked list to list the self-organized because it would be more efficient. A good idea would be to use a linked list implementation of the STL library.

Comment: This is the start of a good answer.  Please edit your answer and address more of the specifics within the question.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't answer my question

Comment: Was this answer written by a bot?